# Trouble resolving stack overflow error

Tags: c++, c

I was getting a stack overflow error with the following code:

```
void f {
    f();
}

int main() {
   f();
   return 0;
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: "*Stack Overflow Problems is usually caused by a corrupt registry entry.*" *LOL*

Comment: That's recursion without base case -> infinite loop

Comment: This is a troll, I bet ... :-)

Comment: Every part of this question is baffling. You wrote a program that makes no sense, and you magically expect some random generic recipe to make your program make sense?

Comment: It does compile under MSVC 2013 (debug, no optimization, -Wall), does cause a stack overflow, but the compiler did warn about it.

Comment: @Brad Larson, you removed the link from my question, which was the whole point of it.

Comment: @Carlton - The whole point was a spammy-looking website that provided scam tools that had nothing to do with programming? I don't see how that could possibly be.

Comment: @Carlton Yeah, it was funny. You had your laugh. Now, back to the serious questions, OK?

Comment: I posted it for the laughs.  I'll remove the question now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the function `f` calls itself. That creates an infinite loop which exhausts the stack and crashes the program.

What are you expecting that this function should do?

```
void f {
    f();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first function (`f`) is a recursive function.  On each call to `f`, the function `f` will be called again. This causes new stack frames to be created. Now, there is no exit condition, and thus `f` will be called over and over again. Eventually, you will run out of stack frames, and stackoverflow will happen.

There are two ways to solve this problem.

**1. Use Tail Recursion Optimization.**
To do this, compile with -O2 if using gcc. So, use the following command.
`gcc -O2 $filename -o $executableName`
This will optimize `f` for tail recursion, and essentially create an infinite loop instead of creating a jump and link in the assembly.
Note that Tail Recursion Optimization *only* works when the last thing you do in a function is to call another function (that is, if the last thing you do causes the stack frame to be no longer needed).

**2.  Add an Exit Condition**
This depends on what you want to do exactly. Suppose you want to recurse three times. Then you will need to pass a parameter to `f` on each call. Then, in `f`, check whether or not the condition for exit is `true`. If so, just `return`. If not, then call `f` again, with a new parameter.

Comment: This answer (1) only makes sense if you think that the OP would prefer a program that locks up and has to killed be manually to a program that crashes with stack overflow. I don't understand why you suggested this.

Comment: @ChrisBeck Well, I'm assuming the OP posted the code as an example. That is, the OP will likely have some code before the recursive call to `f` in `f`, including an exit condition. In this case, Tail Recursion becomes useful if the recursive call might go over the stack frame limit before reaching the exit condition.